# WP Plugin calling PHP function with ajaxrequest

Tags: jquery, ajax, wordpress, post

The front-end contains a button who calles a js function which then should call a php function. this is according to what i read about php beeing a server-language and cannot be directly used to handle onclick events.

So onclick of a button placed on a specific page on the front-end, it calls the script.js function onclick="sendAjaxRequest(true);"

I have a js file called script.js in my plugin folder with following code:

```
function my_enqueue() {

    wp_enqueue_script( 'ajax-script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/my-ajax-script.js', array('jquery') );

    wp_localize_script( 'ajax-script', 'my_ajax_object',
            array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_enqueue' );
function sendAjaxRequest(value){
jQuery.ajax({
 url: my_ajax_object.ajax_url,
 type: 'POST',
 data: ({action : 'get_my_option', value:value}),
      success: function( response ) {
       console.log( response );
      }

 });
}
```

And the php pluginfile called wsn-plugin.php with following code-lines:

```
wp_enqueue_script('wsn-script', plugin_dir_url(__FILE__) . 'script.js');
wp_efunction your_function_name() 
{

// wp_enqueue_script( 'myfunction', get_template_directory_uri().'/assets/js/applicantid.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0',true);
 wp_localize_script( 'myfunction', 'my_ajax_script', array( 'ajaxurl' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );


}

add_action('template_redirect', 'your_function_name');




function get_my_option()
{
    //get applicant id (looks like this is what you want to get back?)

    //send json headers
    header( "Content-Type: application/json" );

    //print out you response as json
    echo json_encode( $value );

    //must have an exit in the ajax action callback!
    exit();

}
add_action("wp_ajax_nopriv_get_my_option", "get_my_option");
add_action("wp_ajax_get_my_option", "get_my_option");nqueue_script('wsn-script');
```

After firing the script by clicking the button i get the error message: "Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected string" and the debuger stops at a specific point in the jquery.js file if i skip this point there it goes to the next and to the next.

What am I missing?

Comment: _“and the debuger stops at a specific point”_ - which one …? Have you checked what your AJAX request was _actually_ answered with, using your browser dev tools network panel?

Comment: `add_action` is a php function and it shouldn't be included in `script.js`

Comment: @Mojo Allmighty i deleted the add action which was from another stackoverflow topic an put it into wsn-plugin.php now i'm getting the error message: "Warning: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid callback, function 'my_enqueue' not found or invalid function name in C:\xampp\htdocs\wp\wp-includes\class-wp-hook.php on line 286" as soon as i load the page

Comment: @CBroe starting in the jquery.js at line 10349 then goes to wp-emoji-releas..n.js on line 2 (why the hack?) flipping trough almost everyfile like bootstrap.min.js

Comment: because you need to copy the callback function ( this case it's `my_enqueue`) along with your add_action

Comment: @Mojo Allmighty, so do i get you right that i copy the whole my_enqueue function into the wsn-plugin.php file? i shortly tried that and it gives me the error: "GET http://localhost/wp/wp-content/themes/wsn/js/my-ajax-script.js?ver=4.9.5 404 (Not Found)"

Comment: You're on the right path now. From now on it's just a matter of path for you. Make sure they are valid and they are pointing to whatever file you need to.

Comment: What i don't get here is, do i need to direct to my own file script.js or to a general ajax file which is handling the request? :S

Comment: So i did the pathchange to my own script.js file and the error is gone but i always get a null response doesn't matter what i send

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For completion change the php file to:

```
<?php
   /*
   Plugin Name: WSN Plugin
   description: Maintain all the connections to LimeSurvey
   Version: 0.2
   Author: M.Huber
   Author URI: www.moritzhuber.ch
   License: GPL2
   */

//reference to the backend ajax framework   
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'ajax_test_enqueue_scripts' );
function ajax_test_enqueue_scripts() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'test', plugins_url( '/test.js', __FILE__ ), array('jquery'), '1.0', true );
    wp_localize_script( 'test', 'ajax_object', array( 'ajax_url' => admin_url( 'admin-ajax.php' ) ) );
}

// to reference the ajax call to this function
add_action( 'wp_ajax_nopriv_call_this', 'new_company_variable_transfer' );
function new_company_variable_transfer() {
    echo 'Did we get here?';
    wp_die();
}
```

and the js file should look like this:

```
function callAjax(){
    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: ajax_object.ajax_url,
        data:{action:'call_this'},
        success:function(response) {
        alert(response);
        $("#result").html(response);
        }
    });
}
```